# col-*-12 (col-xs / col-sm / etc) use in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I see something like the following in code examples on StackOverflow and in themes for sale even (never in Bootstrap's examples).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <p>Words go here</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
       <p>Words go here</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**It drives me nuts because both are incorrect for full width single columns as per Bootstrap's own documentation and common sense.**

[image]

When do you actually use the grid system? When does `col-*-12` come into play?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If something is full width, you don't need it at all.

[image]
*Learn: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/*

The correct html for both of the above examples is this:

```
<div class="container">

       <p>Words go here</p>

      </div> <!--/.container for entire grouping of elements you do not want to exceed the width(s) set in the CSS for this class -->
```

If you want your columns to be full width, it will be under the last column class you used. The following will be full width below where the col-sm- min-width starts (so 767px and UNDER in a default download of Bootstrap 3.x).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     Stuff
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     Stuff
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-8 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

*Don't forget the outer .container or .container-fluid (one per grouping of content that does not change width). The .container or .container-fluid zeros out the negative margin on the .row so you won't get horizontal scroll bars.*

The situations when you use col-*-12 is where you want a full width AFTER the min-width of the smaller column class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
     Stuff
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 col-md-12 -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     Stuff
   </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 col-md-12 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Anyway, col-*-12 comes in handy in nesting situations, especially with forms.

Answer (score 27):

Your frustration is right.. `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` is totally redundant.

Because Bootstrap 3+ is mobile first, any col-classes you declare travel up, meaning they apply to the declared device (xs, sm, md, lg) and larger. So, `col-xs-12 col-sm-12` is redundant. Just use `col-xs-12` for the same effect.

Also, if you don't declare an xs class, the layout will default to col-*-12 once below the smalles col-class you do declare. e.g. `<div class="col-sm-6">` is half-width on `sm` and up, but full-width on `xs`. Whereas `<div class="col-md-6">` is half width on `md` and up, but full width on `sm` and `xs`.

This being said, you should always declare at least one col-class, so it gets the relevant padding and other styling specifics.

Comment: But it does already. If you don't declare but you are inside a .container or .container-fluid the padding will be there as the way it works is by adding the same padding on the L and R as the negative margin on the row so you don't need the row or the column classes if it's full width. Even Bootstrap's own examples say "No grid classes are necessary..."

Comment: You don't need col-xs-12 but in very select situations which I can't think of and have never used.

Comment: if you use col-sm-4 and col-sm-8 the padding will be there on smaller viewports because those are specified outside the media query, only the widths and the floats are included inside the media query.

Comment: col-xs-12 col-sm-12 is not necessary, not even row. Just see, as long as there is a .container/.container-fluid you don't need it.

Comment: I beg to differ: http://www.bootply.com/9IVZg46lsb. Unless you're using no col-classes anywhere, a non-col-class div's content won't line up with others.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the scenario I had or the one in which Bootstrap says no grid classes are required. If you want the padding on a nested element to match others in a row, yes, but if you want to just be full width, then it's not needed.

Comment: You didn't mention a specific scenario. Although you don't HAVE to use grid classes at all, I think this is a pretty common use, since it's the heart of what makes Bootstrap responsive...

Comment: I added the image where in Bootstrap's examples they write "No grid classes are necessary for full-width elements" This is not a situation when it's in a row. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Wow I never saw that! You're right that it says that (here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid), but I think they should explain it more... because when you mix it with other grid classes the design definitely falls apart.

Comment: Yeah, they should explain it more, if the element is inside a row it must be in a column class or it won't clear and it will have other issues. Seeing on the vote down on the ?, apparently this col-X-12 is not understood well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62368/discussion-between-shawn-taylor-and-christina).

Comment: Thanks for this!