# Strange Bootstrap 3 grid behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Html-Code example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" id="div1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" id="div2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

After spending quite a lot of time I discovered that if you don't specify all rules on specific @media size, bootstrap behaves on a strange way.

In this example on small devices "`div3`" becomes a container of `div1`, `div2` and all the content (ex: `buttons`) isn't more accessible.

Shouldn't be defined a default rule? like `col-sm-12`, or is right this way?

It has been very tricky to find out.

*EDIT*

Bootstrap doc says:

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element
>   will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large
>   devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

In this case `col-md-12` apply on small devices in a strange way.

Comment: You should read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`col-sm-6` has `float: left`. Since `col-md-12` dosen't have float, it will appear on top of other columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" id="div1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't true. I can have multiple cols that wraps and also should in some cases.

Comment: Okay, some cases it should indeed. Edited my answer. `col-sm-*` has `float:left`, what causes these problems.

Comment: shouldn't be defined by bootstrap a default of col-sm-12 if not defined?

Comment: `col-md-6` is half size on screen sizes `md` and up. `xs` and `sm` will be automatically 100%. So if you use `col-sm-12`, it's not necessary. This comes in when you don't want full-width column. If you set size class to one column, you should set same size classes to every column. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165996/col-12-col-xs-col-sm-etc-use-in-bootstrap-3).

Comment: I understand how it works and that priority is from xs up to lg, the problem I'm facing is that there isn't a default col-*-12. I think I should get used to define col-xs-12 instead of col-md-12 as default.

Comment: There is really no difference if you use `col-xs-12` or `col-md-12`. Both will have 100% width, since `div` is block element. These classes will just set correct `padding` values.

Comment: Ok, yes you are right. when using col different from 12 (caused by float left, as you said), a row has to be used to have a correct layout.