# How can I adjust the Bootstrap column grouping?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a column of content where I'm trying to stack them one after each each other, and this is happening because of the float, so I've included a `clearfix`, but it's not working.

**Code Example:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">Title</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">Title</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">Title</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">Title</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">sub-title</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Information</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an image example of what I'm after:

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do; if you can post a mockup/image of what you are trying to accomplish that would be best.

Comment: @vanburenx just updated the post, you can see the image example

Answer (score 0):

When you're nesting columns you still need to use `rows` with the interior column structure just like at any other time.

Also, this (`col-md-6 col-sm-6`) type of [column structure](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is redundant. You'll see the same results if you use `col-md-6 col-sm-6` or `col-sm-6`; both will collapse at 768px which means the `col-md-6` won't be used. Use one or the other depending on which viewport width you want the columns to collapse at. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165996/col-12-col-xs-col-sm-etc-use-in-bootstrap-3) for additional info.

See examples.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Standard Columns</h2>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <h3>Sub-Title 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <h3>Information 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <h3>Sub-Title 2</h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
            1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <h3>Information 2</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Redundant Columns</h2>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <h3>Sub-Title 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <h3>Information 1</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <h3>Sub-Title 2</h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
            1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <h3>Information 2</h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College iContrary to
            popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College i</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Mobile, tablet, desktop Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <div class="alert alert-info">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="alert alert-info">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```