# When the xs viewport is not specified, what happens in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In based on this :

```
<div class = "col-md-3 col-lg-7">
```

In an xs viewport the div will be _____ columns wide.

Comment: Well, did you test it to see what happens?

Comment: Actually, I do not much understand about Grid System.That's why i ask this question. But yes i already tested it. if you provide some resource , it will help me.@Vucko

Comment: You could've just checked Bootstrap's official documentation and take a closer look on the Grid System that way.

Comment: @ProDexorite Unfortunately the documentation isn't really very explicit about what happens.

Comment: Exactly @DavidG , i already follow Bootstrap's official documentation but still little bit confused grid system . And i am new to use bootstrap ~proDexorite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a `col-xs-12` then the column width will only apply at `md` and `lg` screen widths. Once your screen width drops below `md`, the widths don't apply and you basically end up with a normal `div` element which will be 100% width. You will however get some of the Bootstrap rules the apply to all `col-*` classes such as:

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Comment: i have a question @DavidG

Comment: Bootstrap grid system is based 12 columns. Now if sm not specify then it will col-sm-12 right ?

Comment: It's only 12 columns if you use the defaults (you can customise it). But yes, effectively if you don't specify a width as that screen size, then it will be 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

It will take **12** columns div if you don't specify  **col-xs-***.

Have you tried by yourself what happens?

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165996/col-12-col-xs-col-sm-etc-use-in-bootstrap-3) which you can refer.

Hope this helps.